# SQL: Problems with update in a trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I got a problem with my tables, I can't really get my head around this problem. My table looks like this:

**Table 1 - Skilt**
[image: My table]

Yes I know it's not english but it shouldn't be a problem.

I have another table that looks like this:

**Table 2 - Skema**

[image: Table 2]

I have a trigger on my Table 1 which inserts data into Table 2

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Skema_Opdatering]
ON [dbo].[Skilt]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    UPDATE Skema SET Skema.Emne = Skilt.Arbejdsopgave
    FROM Skilt
    WHERE CONVERT(varchar(25),Skema.Tid,108) 
    BETWEEN 
    dateadd(minute,((DATEDIFF(minute, cast(0 as DateTime), skilt.Tid_startet) + 7)/ 15) * 15, cast(0 as DateTime))
    AND
    dateadd(minute,((DATEDIFF(minute, cast(0 as DateTime), skilt.Tid_sluttet) + 7)/ 15) * 15, cast(0 as DateTime))
    AND
    CONVERT(varchar(25),Skema.Tid,105) = CONVERT(varchar(25),Skilt.Dato,105)
    ;
END
```

But my problem is that if I insert/update more than 1 time it doesn't remove the old values from Table 2, I end up with a row that should be NULL but has a value. So my question is how do I reset my table to NULL before another update/insert so my trigger can insert new values?

Answer (score 0):

Try to import data from Table2 and changed the columns into a rows and then Insert records in a third (Junction table) and later you can again modify it.This way you will have more grip on it and chances of mistake will be lesser.

Answer (score 0):

`DATEADD` will return `SMALLDATETIME`, `Skema.Tid` column is `TIME` type. I think you should `CONVERT` OR `CAST` `SMALLDATETIME` to `TIME`

Something like this:

```
-- CONVERT
Skema.Tid = CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(...))

--CAST
Skema.Tid = CAST(DATEADD(...) AS TIME)
```

Comment: You should use alias table instead. Example: Table1 AS T1 then use T1.column

Comment: `SELECT A.Date_Column FROM TABLEA AS A
INNER JOIN TABLEB AS B
ON B.Time_Column = CAST (A.Date_Column AS Time)`